# WxPython - displaying the terminal output upto a specific line

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Currently I am able to display my python console output in wxPython GUI. Below is the code for it: -

```
class RedirectText(object):
            def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
                self.out = aWxTextCtrl

            def write(self,string):
                self.out.WriteText(string)

        self.console = wx.TextCtrl(self.window_2_pane_2, wx.ID_ANY, "Low Power Demo Suite [Version Beta]\nC:\Software\Python\Visualizer> Running Simulation...", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
        self.console.SetMinSize((600, 200))
        self.console.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.console.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        redir = RedirectText(self.console)
        sys.stdout = redir
```

The code is working perfectly fine.
However what I want is, I want to display the console output in WxPython upto a specific line only.

How can I do the same?

Thanks
Regards,
Tanmay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are redirecting `sys.stdout` the easiest way would be to cancel that, based on a test on the console output or a line count, or whatever your criteria is.

Before you reassign `sys.stdout` to `redir` save the original setting with:

```
oldstdout = sys.stdout
```

Then whenever your criteria is hit, reapply it with:

```
sys.stdout = oldstdout
```

Comment: Hey,
How do I check for a specific string, so that I can stop the redirection of std.out when that is encountered on the python console?

Comment: @TANMAYAGRAWAL You haven't given us a working example, just a code snippet, so I'm not 100% sure but in your snippet, `string`, one assumes, contains the actual text that is being written.

Comment: @TANMAYAGRAWAL p.s. remember to test against `string.strip()` if you are looking for something specific, because `string` will contain newline characters.

Comment: Hi @Rolf of Saxony this is the entire working code for having a console embedded in wxPython. Even I'm not sure what string is, this is the code I got while searching the internet.
But it doesn't solve my problem completely.

Comment: Sorry, but I still couldn't understand how are you recommending to stop writing to the embedded console once I encounter a specific string.
Can you please elaborate more?